# iOS Home Screen Widget: Any feasible way to update the widget content when app is terminated?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

## Context:

- I am developing a simple widget that displays a string.
- I want to update this string once a day with data retrieved from the server (requesting or receiving it, no preferences; I just want to be able to update the widget with server data)
- I am using Flutter for the main app, and for the widget is natively on iOS
- **Problem: Not finding a feasible way to retrieve server data when the app is terminated (swapped away from the app draw).**

I am open to either a flutter, native iOS solution or a mix of both.

## What I have tried:

### **Using Workmanager package:**

On Flutter, I tried scheduling a periodic task to fetch data from Firebase. For Android, it worked well, but following the documentation, the iOS does not support period tasks, just one time off.

### **Sending a notification or silent notification via Firebase Cloud Messaging:**

On Flutter, tried using firebaseMessasingBackgroundHandler, but as per the documentation:

> On iOS, if the user swipes away the application from the app switcher, it must be manually reopened for background messages to start working again

The statement seems true since, for Android, it was handled correctly, and I achieved the desired outcome. But for iOS, nops.

Outcome:

- **When in the foreground**, notifications (push and silent) are received and handled correctly in Android and iOS.
- **When in the background or terminated:** Push notifications are displayed in Android and iOS. But I cannot handle the notification content and update my widget.

Python Google Cloud Function

```
# Imports
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import messaging

# Regular Push Notification
    title = 'Title Text'
    body = 'Notification Body'

    regular_message = messaging.Message(
        notification=messaging.Notification(
            title=title,
            body=body
        ),
        token=token,
    )

    # Send regular push notification
    regular_response = messaging.send(regular_message)


# Silent Push Notification
    textA = 'Title Text'
    textB = 'Notification Body'

    silent_message = messaging.Message(
        data={
            'textA': textA,
            'textB': textB,
            'content_available': '1',
        },
        token=token,
    )

    # Send silent notification
    silent_response = messaging.send(silent_message)
```

Flutter FirebaseMessaging code

```
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  //Setup FCM
  await setupFirebaseCloudMessaging();

  //Set up background message handler
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
 
  runApp(MyApp());
}

uture<void> setupFirebaseCloudMessaging() async {
  try {
    // Request FCM permission
    final messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

    final settings = await messaging.requestPermission(provisional: true);

    print('Permission granted: ${settings.authorizationStatus}');

    //Register with FCM
    // It requests a registration token for sending messages to users from your App server or other trusted server environment.
    String? token = await messaging.getToken();
    if (token != null) {
      print('Registration Token=$token');
      await persistToken(token);
    }

    // Set up foreground message handler
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {

      if (message.data.containsKey('content_available') &&
          message.data['content_available'] == '1') {

        // Silent Notification (Data-only)
        print('Handling silent notification');

        // Access data from the data payload
        String textA = message.data['textA'];
        String textB = message.data['textB'];
     

        // Uses HomeWidget package to store in user defaults
        updateWidget(textA, texB);
      } else {
        // Regular Push Notification
        print('Handling regular push notification');

        // Add the message to the stream for normal notification
        _messageStreamController.sink.add(message);

      }
    });

  } catch (e) {
    print('Error setting up FCM: $e');
  }
}


Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
 

  if (message.data.containsKey('content_available') &&
          message.data['content_available'] == '1') {

        // Silent Notification (Data-only)
        print('Handling silent notification');

        // Access data from the data payload
        String textA = message.data['textA'];
        String textB = message.data['textB'];
     

        // Uses HomeWidget package to store in user defaults
        updateWidget(textA, texB);
  } else {
    // Regular Push Notification
    print('Handling regular push notification');
  }
}
```

## What I expect:

After circling around I found many (intentional) iOS limitations regarding what a terminated app can do when terminated or in background.
**However, how does one update a home screen widget with server data when the app is terminated?**
Many apps do that, but I am miserably failing to do so. I don't care if there is a flutter or native solution, I just want to have finally peace with that.

### Documentation and other stacks questions I already check:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive
- https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_workmanager/blob/main/IOS_SETUP.md
- https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9300
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app#
- [Flutter FCM NOT handling messages when app terminated on IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76238055/flutter-fcm-not-handling-messages-when-app-terminated-on-ios)
- [Fetch data in iOS with flutter even if the application is terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66049267/fetch-data-in-ios-with-flutter-even-if-the-application-is-terminated)
- [iOS push notifications and AppDelegate methods behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42442833/ios-push-notifications-and-appdelegate-methods-behaviour)
- And countless others

Comment: I have this same issue.

Comment: Hope these articles might help. If so, could you please respond on any updates?

https://medium.com/@aymen_farrah/keeping-an-ios-widget-up-to-date-in-flutter-bcc01f6d114f
https://medium.com/swlh/advanced-widgets-network-calls-deeplinking-intent-configuration-30c697e09789